# Extjs5 treepanel [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm having a problem with treepanel in extjs5. when I create a tree panel like this:

`Ext.syncRequire(['Ext.tree.Panel',
                  'Ext.form.Label',
                  'Ext.window.*',
                  'Ext.data.TreeStore'
]);`

`var myTreePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
});`

then in the same file I have:

`//Window view:`

`var treeViewWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
     items:[myTreePanel]
});`

`Ext.application({
    name: 'Training App',
    launch: function () {
         treeViewWindow.show();
    }
});`

This doesn't work, and give me the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` in `Component.js:5421`

note that if I changed the treepanel with panel, it works.
and if I put the whole code inside the lunch function (the window and treepanel variables) then it works too!

can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to define store.

```
store: store
```

[You code in fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/965)